# Bought wifi adapter t600u plus but when i looked if it works it says that I have archer t2u

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 22.04, tp-link

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. After I plugged the adapter in I didn't check if the adapter worked and installed drivers for the t2u wireless adapter by mistake. After I did that I think I uninstalled the drivers for the t2u. Still when I plug my t600u plus it still says that I plugged in a t2u adapter. I also managed to get the t600u drivers from the official website, but I don't know how to install it.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` with the adapter inserted. Welcome to Ask  Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter is working after I downloaded the driver from this site:https://www.kalilinux.in/2023/04/best-budget-wifi-adapter-for-kali-linux.html